# Is Gradle Wrapper command part of AGP or Gradle?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

We cannot see an answer to the question on whether command like `./gradlew lint` is part of Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) or the Gradle itself. We are getting error when executing lint but it seems a bug with the lint itself and we are not sure if we supposedly report it on AGP or Gradle.

Logs:

`Error: Unexpected failure during lint analysis of ActivityExt.kt (this is a bug in lint or one of the libraries it depends on)`

No error in the code nor lint warning and this is working before the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `./gradlew lint` command is actually a way to invoke the lint function that is bundled as part of the Android SDK, using gradle.

So the bug with the lint tool should be reported to Android.

Comment: Yes I just realized it lately, the lints are being provided by the Android component and Gradle command is the way to execute them.